# getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders input from Messaging.InboundEmail type issue

Tags: apex-email-service

I am trying to use the function getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders from a custom email service in Salesforce. I am not sure what I am missing. The class already implements...

```
public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail emailMessage, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope)
```

So why doesn't this work...

```
emailId = getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders(emailMessage.headers);
```

I am getting the following error trying to save the class. Is the emailMessage.headers not already a list of headers?

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders(List<Messaging.InboundEmail.Header>) from the type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is part of "Cases" class.

Try Cases.getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders(emailMessage.headers);

Please see:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_Cases_getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders.htm

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the Class declaration part since I was thinking this was on the email object.